# React Pin Input with React Simple Keyboard not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying if there is any way to give a built-in Numeric keyboard for Ipad view.

React Pin Input doesn't seem to take the input field values.

I tried to add a different class for the input field so that I can add the values manually. But even adding values manually doesn't seem to work. Length is working fine but somehow React Pin Input is not taking the values manually.

```
 if (input.length == 1) {
  document.querySelector(".input-1").value = input;
}
if (input.length == 2) {
  document.querySelector(".input-2").value = input;
}
if (input.length == 3) {
  document.querySelector(".input-3").value = input;
}
if (input.length == 4) {
  document.querySelector(".input-4").value = input;
}
```

My question is how to add values and attributes to React Pin Input on the key press which is a virtual keyboard.

Added manual ID outside of component class but still, values is not working as typing from the keyboard.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pin-input-forked-3mo8xm

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want your pin input to work with the native keyboard on iPad, or the virtual keyboard that you render on the screen (`react-simple-keyboard`)?

Comment: I want to make it work in the virtual keyboard thats loading in the screen. Ipad doesnt have number only keyboad as iphone or other smart phone. Couldn't figure out how to put those keyboard numbers inside each input field as a value to send it to another page in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with [React Pin Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pin-input) is, that it's not taking the value if it is not from the physical keyboard or OS keyboard.
Check This example here. A simple way of assigning the value to an input field is by assigning value to

```
this.state.xyz
```

xyz will have whatever is clicked from the on-screen keyboard. As its shown in the example below. This was using [React Simple Keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-keyboard)

https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/simple-keyboard/react-simple-keyboard-input-mask-demo/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

But [React Pin Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pin-input) allows us to make multiple inputs fields by checking whats the value of the length passed into it. They have other attributes but not `values` attribute. Which makes it hard to insert values into the input field generated by [React Pin Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pin-input)

When I raised a question, I was selecting the input field via querySelector which was creating an issue. There is no different class or id to the `input` field generated by React Pin Input. So I was also adding class to in input field to read the `value` of it. For example:

```
const firstLi = document.querySelector(
".pincode-input-container input:nth-of-type(1)"
);
firstLi.setAttribute("id", "input-1");

document.querySelector("#input-1").value = input;
```

Even now also I haven't got the answer but found a better approach to do it. Still, I am manually adding values to the input field and it is working better than the querySelector approach but i am still using `window.location.reload();` to clear the pin if the input doesn't match. Check out the example below. There is 2 input field one is generated by React Pin Input another one is a normal input.

```
this.pin.elements[0].state.value = button;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-rgb-qnm081?file=/src/Pin.js:1517-1559

If anyone has a better approach than this, please do let us know. For future will make a github repo including both components.

Answer (score 0):

Confetti are above the numpad and prevent users from clicking on it.

Plus the Submit handler was not bound.

So, I added `pointerEvents: "none"` on confetti plus bound your handlers.

Does it work for you now?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pin-input-forked-in7qtw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you for trying. But I want something that can add values easily into those input fields just by doing `value={this.state.input}` and updating the input state every time number is clicked to pressed or touched.  Also on submit if the pin doesn't match, i am reloading the browser to hide the errors. but want to do it without reloading by just calling `handleClear function`